# How to mock and test dynamically created objects using google test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest

```
class IA
{
public:
    IA() {}
    virtual ~IA() {}

    virtual void function_1() = 0;
};

// A mock class of actual class 'A'
class A : public IA
{
public: 
    A() {}
    ~A() {}

    MOCK_METHOD0(function_1, void());
};

class B
{
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() {}

    void run(int num_run)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_run; i++)
        {
            A a();
            a.function_1();
        }
    }
};

TEST()
{
    // how to test b.run will actual call A::function_1() for 5 times?
    B b();
    b.run(5);
}
```

Based on the code above, I would like to test the behaviour of class B. Class B uses Class A, and in this case, I've a mocked class A. Since google test EXPECT_CALL() requires the actual object that is expecting function to be called, EXPECT_CALL() wouldn't work here. This is because the mocked 'A' object has yet being created before b.run() being called, and there's no way to get its object as it's within b.run scope, and it will immediate destroyed after. Is there anyway to test the behaviour under this circumstance? How to test that mock 'A' is created 5 times and how to test A.function_1() is being called 5 times.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use some form of *dependency injection*. There are various ways to do this:

- Using function arguments.
- Using templates.
- Using a virtual factory function.

An example using templates:

```cpp
class B
{
...
  template <class T>
  void run(int num_run)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_run; ++i)
    {
      T a();
      a.function_1();
    }
  }
}; ​
```

You can now use your mock for *`T`* in your tests.

Also, class `IA` no longer needs to have virtual functions for this test, unless you need these virtual functions for other code.

See the Google Mock [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods) for details.